# node.js:Request aborted at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted multiparty in sails.js framework

Tags: node.js, sails.js, multiparty

I have  file upload system in node.js with multiparty package

```
        var gm          = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
        var multiparty  = require('multiparty');

        var form        =  new multiparty.Form();

        var s3          =  sails.config.aws.main();

        var options     = {
            partSize: 5242880, queueSize: 1
        }
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

            gm(files.fileToUpload[0].path)
                .resize(200,200,'^')
                .stream(function (err,buffer) {

                    s3.upload({
                        Bucket:'mybucket',
                        Body:buffer,
                        Key:'artwork-croppedimages/test.jpg'
                    },options,function(err, data) {
                        console.log("upload error",err);
                        console.log("data",data);
                    });

                 })

        });
```

Its works fine but when upload larger files usually greater than 20 MB i got this error

```
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/var/www/node/cushbuart/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:183:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:381:9)
    at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:375:3)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:511:12)
```

I know its solved with increase the timeout but i don't know how to in sails.js framerwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request timeout is a feature of Node.js; there's nothing Sails-specific about it.  From the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback):

> ## request.setTimeout(timeout[, callback])
>
> Added in: v0.5.9
>
> - `timeout` `<number>` Milliseconds before a request is
>     considered to be timed out.
> - `callback` `<Function>` Optional function to
>     be called when a timeout occurs. Same as binding to the timeout event.
>
> Once a socket is assigned to this request and is connected
>   socket.setTimeout() will be called.

So in your Sails.js action, do `req.setTimeout(4 * 60 * 1000)` if you want to increase the timeout to 4 minutes.

You might also look into using the [built-in file upload capabilities](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads) of Sails!

Comment: But i need to add in every controller is there any way to set globally in sails.js

Comment: The default Node server timeout is set by `server.timeout` (see docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)).  You can access the raw HTTP server in Sails via `sails.hooks.http.server` (as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269988/access-base-http-server-of-sails-js)).  So, `sails.hooks.http.server=<timeout in milliseconds>`.  Google is your friend!